# A first chance exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, directoryservices

I have an Asp.Net MVC 2 application with Windows Authentication enabled. Till yesterday, it was working fine. Today when I hit F5, I'm getting the exception. I googled but nothing helped. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able get the actual exception by setting "Break when an exception is:" - checking "Thrown" for System.DirectoryServices.Protocols in Debug -> Exceptions menu in VS 2010. The error was, the AD Server was not reachable and credential were invalid.